# Which axioms are used for constructing collection of subsets from a collection of sets?

Tags: set-theory

Assume we have a collection of sets $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$. Let us also assume that for $i \in I$, we have some (and possibly multiple) $B_i \subseteq A_i$ satisfying some property. What exactly do we need to invoke (if anything) to construct a collection $\{B_i \}_{i \in I}$ such that if $i \in I$ then $B_i \subseteq A_i$ satisfies the property of interest? Here is my analysis. Take $i \in I$. Let $X_i$ be the set containing all possible $B_i \subseteq A_i$ satisfying some particular property. Consider the collection $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$. By the axiom of choice, we have a collection $\{B_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that if $i \in I$ then $B_i \in X_i$. This is the collection that we were initially interested in. Now to my question. Is this analysis correct? Also, do we need to invoke anything to construct the collection $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.  There is nothing special you need to do to construct the collection $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$: you have an explicit, specific definition of it, namely that for each $i\in I$, $$X_i=\{B:B\subseteq A_i\text{ and $B$ has property $P$}\}$$ where "property $P$" is just whatever property you're talking about.  The axiom of choice is only needed to get the existence of a collection if you can't specifically define what each member of the collection is (you just know some property you want each member to have, but that property does not define a unique object).

(In ZFC set theory, for instance, you can construct the set $X_i$ using the axiom of power sets on $A_i$ and then the axiom of separation on the power set of $A_i$, and then you can construct the collection $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ using the axiom of replacement.)